# Hooking IAT function of a game

Tags: c++, hook, portable-executable

I am messing around with some dll injections/hooking.
I already tried to hook the Sleep function of the IAT in my own application, which worked perfectly fine, but then I tried to do the same in a computer game  and got a crashes instead.

Since I inject a dll and hook the IAT of the executable module from my dll I cannot see an error(log), but I nailed the error down to this part, which iterates over the IAT:

```
while (impDesc->FirstThunk) {
    auto thunkData = getMemoryPointer<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + impDesc->OriginalFirstThunk));
    int n = 0;

    while (thunkData->u1.Function) {
        char* importFuncName = getMemoryPointer<char>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + (DWORD)thunkData->u1.AddressOfData + 2));  //the function name is stored at .AddressOfData + 2
        if (strcmp(importFuncName, funcName) == 0) {
            auto vfTable = getMemoryPointer<DWORD>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + impDesc->FirstThunk));
            DWORD original = vfTable[n];
            auto oldProtection = protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], PAGE_READWRITE);
            vfTable[n] = newFunc;
            protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], oldProtection);
            return original;
        }
        n++;
        thunkData++;
    }
    impDesc++;
}
```

The code before and in the first loop does get executed, also the code in the second loop. But the if is never called, and also the code after the loops is never called, so somehow the code is breaking in one of this loops but I don't know how or why.

I already tried checking if impDesc or thunkData is NULL, but both if cases never get executed. The function I want to hook from the IAT is the Sleep function.

Does anybody have a clue why this loop can break? Since I tested it on my own application and it worked fine there.

Thats impDesc:

```
auto impDesc = getMemoryPointer<IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + IAT.VirtualAddress));
```

EDIT: I found out that thunkData->u1's address is 8000000e before it crashes. So it crashes at thunkData->u1.Function or at char* importFuncName = getMemoryPointer... when u1 has the value 8000000e. Why that?

EDIT2:
Okey I update my while loop as suggested to ignore ordinals. Here is the updated version:

```
while (impDesc->FirstThunk) {
    IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* thunkData = getMemoryPointer<IMAGE_THUNK_DATA>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + impDesc->OriginalFirstThunk));
    int n = 0;

    while (thunkData->u1.Function) {
        if (IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(thunkData->u1.Function)) {
            n++;
            thunkData++;
            continue;
        }

        auto importFuncName = getMemoryPointer<char>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + (DWORD)thunkData->u1.AddressOfData + 2));   //the function name is stored at .AddressOfData + 2
        if (strcmp(importFuncName, funcName) == 0) {
            auto vfTable = getMemoryPointer<DWORD>((LPVOID)(baseAddress + impDesc->FirstThunk));
            DWORD original = vfTable[n];
            auto oldProtection = protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            vfTable[n] = newFunc;
            protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], oldProtection);
            return original;
        }
        n++;
        thunkData++;
    }
    impDesc++;
}
```

But now it crashes somewhere between those lines:

```
auto oldProtection = protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
vfTable[n] = newFunc;
protectMemory<DWORD>((LPVOID)&vfTable[n], oldProtection);
```

Atleast I can find the Sleep function in the IAT now :)
But somehow I cannot replace it with my function. Does anybody have a clue why?
It's still working when I am doing it for my own application

Comment: 8000000e - this is ordinal. function can be imported by name or by ordinal. you need use `if (!IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(thunkData->u1.Function)) {...}`

Comment: Thanks I will try that :) I will update you as soon as I tested it. And how can I import the ordinal? Like if IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(print name))

Comment: @RbMm Updated my answer :)